# Переменная из названия файла

Tags: python

Запускаю файл liq_753.py
Как внутри кода получить переменную `l = 753`, где **753** это часть названия файла (исполняемого модуля)?

Comment: например можно убирать "стандартную" часть названия - "liq_"

Comment: Что значит "открываю файл"? Запускаете этот файл как скроипт? Или открываете на чтение из другого скрипта?

Comment: просто открываю исполняться

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что Вы хотите с скрипт взять имя самого скрипта. Это возможно, хотя и не всегда. Это где то так делается

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import re
name = sys.argv[0]
m = re.match('liq_(\d+).*', name)
print(m.group(1))
```

проверок добавьте сами по вкусу.

Comment: почему то m это None, а m.group(1) закрывает файл и не дает ему исполняться

Comment: Потому что у Вас неверное имя файла, а о том, что нужно дописать проверку, Я писал

Comment: m равен None, потому что регулярка не нашла ничего - "не поматчилась"

Comment: имя файла name есть, отображается. Что за проверку писать не знаю. название файла такое же

Comment: покажите, как у Вас отображается имя в переменной name

Comment: C:\liq_124.py - вот так

Comment: Ага, тогда должна быть такая регулярка '.*liq_(\d+).*'

Comment: а знаете =) это до сих пор плохо работает через раз. Есть ли какой то другой способ?

Comment: Интересно, почему оно работает "через раз". В целом, использование sys.argv[0] немного ненадёжно, но не до такой же степени. Если не работают регулярки - тогда ищите другие способы парсить строку.